# Create user with SSH key, without password

Tags: gitlab

My campus runs a gitlab server.  I am a user, not an admin.  Campus policy forbids giving LDAP access to off-campus collaborators/co-authors, but has no problem in principle with allowing such folks to have "Developer" level access to non-public repositories on an invitational basis.  Is it possible to have my off-campus colleagues send me an SSH key, and have the gitlab admin create a no-login user with that key who I could then add as a "Developer" member to selected projects?  If it's do-able, what's the magic process so I can pass it along to the IT support folks?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your IT support team to create Gitlab account with specific permissions for those developers without LDAP account. And then simply add them to the repositories and ask them to upload ssh keys.

Comment: I already knew I want to "create Gitlab account with specific permissions," what I don't know is how to do it.  Also, the users can't upload SSH keys if they can't log in.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: This comment is probably >1 year too late ;), but I think you're missing that you can create non-LDAP (local) user accounts in your LDAP-enabled GitLab.